# What is the configuration of the microsoft.com IIS servers?

Tags: iis, iis-6, iis-8

A couple of months ago, I had found a page on a Microsoft Team blog, where the **techs were explaining what configuration they used on their own IIS web servers** running the microsoft.com website behind the scene.

This article was dated several years ago. Infortunately, I have forgotten to bookmark it ! .. and cannot find it again.

Even if some of the information in this article was dated in some aspects, a large portion of it was very relevant to help me configure my own IIS web servers.

Shame on me for not having bookmarked it !

Would I have the chance that one of you can lead me to this blog entry again ? Maybe on archive.org ?

Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this article again !
It was not on a microsoft blog, but on Technet. My fault, sorry.

In this article, the Microsoft Engineering Operations (MSCOM Ops) team share with us which configuration settings they use to tune application pools running the microsoft own servers.

I really thank their team for sharing with us the Microsoft.com Operations settings, that abviously must be adapted for each or our cases.

Here it is ! :-)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx

Hoping having saved the day of many other users in addition to mine ;)